# How can I have 2 fixed headers on 1 page?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a page with a fixed header and below that a table that I'd like to have a fixed table header so when I scroll I always see the page header and then the table header below that. When I try to fix the thead this screws up the column alignment of thead. How do I correct this?

EDIT: My question is how do I get the column headers to line up with the columns?

EDIT: Also note that I need TWO headers...one at the top of the page and another for the table.

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
    #top1{ 
        border-bottom:black; 
        background: #dedede; 
        position:fixed;
        top:0;
        left:0; 
        width:50%;
        color: #000;
        height: 30px;
    }

    #table{
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 28px;
    }
    #table_header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    }
    .col1{
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col2{
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col3{
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    .col4{
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
    <div id="top1">
    blah blah blah
    </div>

    <div id="top2">

    <table id="table">
     <thead id="table_header">
      <tr>
       <th class="col1">column 1</th>
       <th class="col2">column 2</th>
       <th class="col3">column 3</th>
       <th class="col4">column 4</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>


    <tbody>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
  <tr><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td><td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td></tr>
    </tbody>



    </table>
    </div>


    </body>


    </html>
```

Comment: Possible dupliucate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/983031/jquery-how-to-freeze-table-header-and-allow-scrolling-of-the-rest-of-the-rows. Also you're going to need JavaScript to do this as you want to detect scrolling. I'd recommend a jQuery colution.

Comment: yeah, I saw that but it isn't what I'm looking for. First, I need to essentially have TWO fixed headers...one for the page and one for the actual table. Second, the answers suggested add a scrollbar to the table, which I don't want

Comment: Why not place a `div` tag above your table and style it as needed such as `display:block;` or whatever you need and have this as your main header. Maybe use two divs for each header and then your table below the second one

Comment: @Anagio: thx but that didn't seem to work either. It will fix the 2 headers at the top but the column alignment of the table header is still screwed up

Comment: You could add 2 rows under the header tag.<thead id="table_header">
 <tr>
  <th colspan="4" id="top1">Header one</th>
 </tr>      
<tr>
       <th class="col1">column 1</th>
       <th class="col2">column 2</th>
       <th class="col3">column 3</th>
       <th class="col4">column 4</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I caught you right .. I made a **demo** for you http://jsfiddle.net/aV54L/
No jQuery, no JavaScript .. CSS only

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
    margin : 0px;
}

#top1{ 
    border-bottom:black; 
    background: #dedede; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    width:50%;
    color: #000;
    height: 30px;
    z-index:5;
}
.col1{
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col2{
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col3{
    width: 25%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col4{
    width: 15%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

#tableHeader {
    width: 50%;
    top: 20px;
    position:fixed;
    background-color: red;
    z-index:10;
}

#table {
    position: relative;
    width: 50%;
    top: 50px;
    background-color: aqua;
    z-index:0;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="top1">
blah blah blah
</div>

<div id="top2">

<table id="tableHeader" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
 </table>

<table id="table" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td class="col1">column 1</th>
   <td class="col2">column 2</th>
   <td class="col3">column 3</th>
   <td class="col4">column 4</th>
  </tr>      
 </table>
</div>


</body>


</html>
```

As I say in the comment, I think that the **problem with your code** is to give `position:fixed` to thead tag. If it's not needed I suggest to use two tables as shown in the demo to let `positioning` to be understood correctly.
I think this is not a hack as been said but it's accepting things like they work. I tried to change the original code as less as possible however.

Comment: I think this looks pretty good and almost got the right answer. however it uses a hack. ( used another "table" instead of previous "thead") . whatever, vote up.

Comment: @Siwei Shen this is needed for `position:fixed` to be understood correctly .. I think the main goal is `to have 2 fixed headers on 1 page` .. it's not been said `keeping thead`. I tried to change the code as less as possible. I could try to find a solution keeping thead if needed, but I think that's the cause of the problem

Comment: You should not make any table related element either position fixed or absolute(and even relative does not work in, at least, firefox 3.6)
Tables have a very specific set of rules on how things are rendered. For example the tfoot element must be declared above the tbody but it shows below the tbody. With a reason.

Apart from several new problems you introduce writing it like this, the above answer is the nicest.
Just don't forget that browsers will add a tbody element. Possibly breaking your css if you forget about it.(just write the element yourself just in case)

Answer (score 1):

```
#top1{ 
    border-bottom:black; 
    background: #dedede; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    width:50%;
    color: #000;
    height: 30px;
}
#table{
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 28px;
}
#table_header{
    margin-left: -8px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
}
.col1{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col2{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col3{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
.col4{
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
thead tr {
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
}
```

Comment: This will do the trick, it's the percentages on the columns that caused the problem.

Comment: ...tables... gross?  Are you displaying data or just trying to get everything lines up with each other ?

Comment: If it's server generated, it should be easy enough to add the class to the other rows as well (like in a loop)

Comment: it works but I do need to have different sized columns. btw, the table is for displaying data, it isn't for page layout

Answer (score 1):

In order to achieve what you are looking for, just `Css` is not going to help. You need to take help of `JavaScript/jQuery`.

If you want to have a fixed header for a table then you cannot have its `width` `100%` because if you resize the window or the container which holds the table, it is going to resize the table content but the header will not resize automatically. You have to explicitly set the header column width.

I have a jQuery solution with few lines of code and cleaned and removed most of the unwanted css. Take a look at the demo which I have created and let me know how it helps you.

> Note: For the demo I have set table `width` as `600px`. You can set it
>   as per your requirement.

**Final Css**

```
#top1{ 
    border-bottom:black; 
    background: #dedede; 
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0; 
    width:600px;
    color: #000;
    height: 30px;
}
#table{ width:600px;margin-top: 28px; }
#table thead{ background:white; }
.col1{ width: 40%; }
.col2{ width: 20%; }
.col3{ width: 25%; }
.col4{ width: 15%; }
.col1, .col2, .col3, .col4{ border: 1px solid #000; }
.fixedPosition{ position: fixed; }
```

**Js**

```
$(function(){
    var $table = $("#table"), w,
        $columns = $table.find('thead th')
    $table.find('tr:eq(1) td').each(function(i){
        w = $columns.eq(i).width();
        $(this).width(w);
        $columns.eq(i).width(w);
    })
    $table.find('thead').addClass('fixedPosition');
});
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/qKswk/9/)** 

(**Note**: Once the demo page loads please resize the fiddle output window it is very small to accommodate 600px width table and you might see column not aligning with the table and might think this does not solve the problem)

Comment: I don't think your demo have solved the "column alignment" problem. And I can use just "pure" CSS to achieve the same result with yours.

Comment: @SiweiShen - Have you checked the demo link? Once the page loads just resize the output window because jsfiddle do not maintain the window size you will see column mis alignment as there is not enough space. My solution aligns the column perfectly take a look again. If you think you can provide the same solution with pure css then what is stopping you? I think this solution do not deserve a down vote.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add these two attributes to your #tableheader style:

```
top: 36px;
background-color:white;
```

That tells your header what its fixed position should actually be, and prevents the background from being transparent.  Notice, however, that the column widths don't line up with the body, and you can see them around the outer edge of the header.

To get around that, you will likely need to play around with the margin and padding of your header.  You'll also need to give each header column the same width as its corresponding body column.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I still can't get the column headers to align properly

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#top1 {
    border-bottom: black;
    background: #dedede;
    overflow: auto;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 756px;
    color: #000;
    height: 30px;
}

/* define height and width of scrollable area. Add 16px to width for scrollbar          */
div.tableContainer {
    clear: both;
    border: 1px solid #963;
    height: 285px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 756px
}

/* Reset overflow value to hidden for all non-IE browsers.*/
html>body div.tableContainer {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 756px
}

/* define width of table. IE browsers only                 */
div.tableContainer table {
    float: left;
    width: 740px
}

/* define width of table. Add 16px to width for scrollbar.           */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                        */
html>body div.tableContainer table {
    width: 756px
}

/* set table header to a fixed position. WinIE 6.x only                                       */
/* In WinIE 6.x, any element with a position property set to relative and is a child of       */
/* an element that has an overflow property set, the relative value translates into fixed.    */
/* Ex: parent element DIV with a class of tableContainer has an overflow property set to auto */
thead.fixedHeader tr {
    position: relative
}

/* set THEAD element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
html>body thead.fixedHeader tr {
    display: block
}

/* make the TH elements pretty */
thead.fixedHeader th {
    background: #C96;
    border-left: 1px solid #EB8;
    border-right: 1px solid #B74;
    border-top: 1px solid #EB8;
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 4px 3px;
    text-align: left
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
thead.fixedHeader a,thead.fixedHeader a:link,thead.fixedHeader a:visited
    {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: 100%
}

/* make the A elements pretty. makes for nice clickable headers                */
/* WARNING: swapping the background on hover may cause problems in WinIE 6.x   */
thead.fixedHeader a:hover {
    color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    width: 100%
}

/* define the table content to be scrollable                                              */
/* set TBODY element to have block level attributes. All other non-IE browsers            */
/* this enables overflow to work on TBODY element. All other non-IE, non-Mozilla browsers */
/* induced side effect is that child TDs no longer accept width: auto                     */
html>body tbody.scrollContent {
    display: block;
    height: 262px;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%
}

/* make TD elements pretty. Provide alternating classes for striping the table */
/* http://www.alistapart.com/articles/zebratables/                             */
tbody.scrollContent td,tbody.scrollContent tr.normalRow td {
    background: #FFF;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

tbody.scrollContent tr.alternateRow td {
    background: #EEE;
    border-bottom: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    border-top: 1px solid #DDD;
    padding: 2px 3px 3px 4px
}

/* define width of TH elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* Add 16px to last TH for scrollbar padding. All other non-IE browsers. */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body thead.fixedHeader th {
    width: 200px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th+th {
    width: 240px
}

html>body thead.fixedHeader th+th+th {
    width: 316px
}

/* define width of TD elements: 1st, 2nd, and 3rd respectively.          */
/* All other non-IE browsers.                                            */
/* http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors        */
html>body tbody.scrollContent td {
    width: 200px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td+td {
    width: 240px
}

html>body tbody.scrollContent td+td+td {
    width: 300px
}
-->
</style>
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="top1">blah blah blah</div>

    <div id="tableContainer" class="tableContainer">

        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"
            class="scrollTable">
            <thead class="fixedHeader">
                <tr>
                    <th>column 1</th>
                    <th>column 2</th>
                    <th>column 3</th>
                    <th>column 4</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>


            <tbody class="scrollContent">
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                    <td>fjasklfjsdklfjsdlk</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>



        </table>
    </div>

</body>
```

Reference: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Answer (score 0):

Change the margin-top for #table, and a negative margin-top for #table_header (in this example 100px)

```
  #table{
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 128px;
  }
  #table_header{
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    margin-top: -100px;
  }
```

Comment: -1 IE position:Fixed isn't supported in IE6 or iPad pre IOS 5 - Adding to this, is the a way the OP could perhaps gracefully degrade?

Comment: The OP is already using position: fixed, it's rather ludicrous to suggest that this answer doesn't count if it wasn't part of the OPs requirements to support those two platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a CSS framework for this such as Blueprint, that way you get a rock solid all-browser compatible alignment of your divs.

1. Follow simple instructions on http://blueprintcss.org/ on how to add blueprint to your project
2. http://blueprintcss.org/tests/parts/grid.html see this page creating 2 24 grids below each other would give you 2 fixed headers.

All other above suggestions are hard work in css hacking and they could be not compatible across all browsers, therefore blueprint is one of the best tools you can add, its a short learn curve with high revenue in debugging issue

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy. You can effect a lot with the `display`-property.

In this case we style the tbody to flow with the text (and the thead). Then we can add `margin` as distance to the top of the surrounding div. (`padding` also works but is logical wrong.)

```
tbody{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

Additionally you should fill your thead white.

```
thead{
    background:#ffffff;
}
```

Ask if you have any questions!

edit: I want to mention that this is a pure css solution. You used `position:fixed` so I think it is ok for you. Notice that this property don't work on mobile devices (understand as `position:absolute`) and Internet Explorer 6 (ignores it).

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use datatables.net's fixed header plugin this will fix the table header so you can scroll down and always see the tables th headers, then use a fixed div tag above the table like I posted earlier http://datatables.net/extras/fixedheader/

Answer (score 0):

I've come up with a CSS only solution which works (at least on chrome). You can see it [here at jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/magicalex/ttXAZ/).
The HTML:

```
<div id="header">this seems to work</div>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
      <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
      </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Some datum</td>
    <td>Some other datum</td>
    <td>yet another datum</td>
    <td>the final bit of data</td>
  </tr>
    <!--etc etc etc-->
  <tr>
    <td>Some datum</td>
    <td>Some other datum</td>
    <td>yet another datum</td>
    <td>the final bit of data</td>
  </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The CSS:

```
    * {
  padding: 0;
   margin: 0; 
}
#header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 20px;
    background: blue;
    width: 80%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    z-index: 9;
}
table {
}
thead {
    background: blue;
    position: fixed;
    top: 20px;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 10;
}
tbody {
    background: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    width: 80%;
    z-index: 0;
}
thead tr {
    background: red;
    width: 100%;
    display:block;
}
thead tr th:last-child {
}
thead tr {
}
tr {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
td,th {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 20%;
}
th {
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
td {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: -4px;
}
tr th:first-of-type,
tr td:first-of-type {
    width: 29%;
}
tr th:last-of-type,
tr td:last-of-type {
    width: 29%;
}
```

Could probably benefit from some tightening up, but it seems to fulfill the OP's criteria.

Comment: Just checked, and it works on firefox too. Would need to set a min-width if browser window gets too small, though.